# Mechanize error with

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I installed Python 2.7, BeautifulSoup and mechanize. I can't manage to open page. I get message:

```
<response_seek_wrapper at 0x2d89348L whose wrapped object =<closeable_response at 0x2d89988Lwhose fp = <socket._fileobjectobject at 0x0000000002D4CE58>>>
```

This is the code:

```
import mechanize
br=mechanize.Browser()
url = 'http://www.google.com' (or any other)
br.open(url)
```

I tried to Google error text it but it is not finding anything. It is like something is missing but I watched many tutorials and forums and they just use open method without preparing the virtual browser. I tried IDLE and command prompt but I get the same message. My OS is Windows7.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't mean it is not working. It opens the page and returns the `response` object which you don't need to use. Just continue using `br` after calling the `open()`:

```
>>> import mechanize
>>> br = mechanize.Browser()
>>> url = 'http://www.google.com'
>>> br.open(url)
<response_seek_wrapper at 0x11164ed88 whose wrapped object = <closeable_response at 0x111653320 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x111648250>>>
>>> br.title()
'Google'
```

Comment: @Djusko ok, thanks, let me know if need further help with it.

Comment: You were correct but now I am experiencing some other problems during my mechanize/beautifulsoup learning. Is there a way to click on a button with mechanize or BS? I have a input field with several buttons that execute something so there is no SUBMIT. With what I can click buttons? I found that mechanize do not interpret javascript and the page I am making script is full of buttons. What should I do?

Comment: @Djusko yeah, you need to give `selenium` a try. Consider creating a separate question if u need help with it.

Comment: Duh... I was learning python these days to figure that I can't do this with it... and they closed my previous question as to broad when I asked what should I learn to achieve what I want. :)
Thank you so much and can you tell me some useful link to learn Selenium sintax? I used it years ago but only for simple clicks, but now I need some data mining from opened pages, copy it to variables, paste it to other pages... can Selenium do all of it??

Comment: @Djusko yup, `selenium` can do this. It is also powerful in terms of [locating elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html). Docs are pretty good, there is a lot of info here on SO too. If you need help, just ask and throw me a link too. Thanks.

Comment: I see that selenium may be used with other programming languages such as Python, so I can combine those two to to get what I want... is this a good start?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7z1RIJfjbnc

Comment: Please look if you can my other question about selenium(I do not have other ways to contact you here):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109337/how-to-make-selenium-webdriver-not-to-wait-for-whole-page-to-load?noredirect=1#comment39133457_25109337