# How to make Selenium WebDriver not to wait for whole page to load

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using python 2.7 with Selenium webdriver for Firefox and I have a problem I can't solve or find solved on the internet.
My task is to open around 10k web pages (adsl router web interfaces - via ip address) and upload new firmware. I wrote the code but in order to finish it I must learn how to make selenium webdriver not to wait for page load like forever, but to wait for 2 minutes(it is time needed for new firmware to upload) and then proceed to next step.
I thought I let it wait for forever (wait for router to reconnect - much slower but doable by me without help) but the catch is when I click upload button it takes 2 minutes of uploading new firmware, then router reboots to apply changes (takes less then 2 minutes), then tries to connect (around 10 seconds) and even then if it gets some other IP it will never load and my program wait for forever.
So, I want to skip all of that and I want program to proceed to next router after first 2 minutes. Can it be done? I read something about "pageLoadingStrategy" but I couldn't understand how to use it.
Please write me if it is not understandable, because English is not my native language. Below you can see the code sample, after button.submit() it should wait for 2 minutes and proceed and not wait forever:

```
def firmware_upload():
  global ip
  br.get("http://"+ip+"/upload.html")
  button = br.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file" and @name="filename"]')
  button.send_keys("/home/djura/Downloads/KW5815A_update_140417")
  button.submit()
  print ("Odradjen UPDATE SOFTWARE-a!")
  return
```

Comment: "My task is to open around 10k web pages ... and upload new firmware" -- I believe this task is not sort of UI automation (i.e. not Selenium job) but rather something related to load testing. For example can be done with Grinder or JMeter.

Comment: O, but it is UI automation. I must log on to every router and check if it needs to be upgraded.
If you have another advice how to do it, please share. This what I know to do, so I use Selenium.

Comment: now that you mention other ways to do it... I can try over telnet... but if I can make Selenium do not wait it would be super because I have ready program for my job.

Comment: scratch that telnet way... both version print the same over telnet :-(

Comment: Well, you can try to use JMeter. Write very simple script or modify existing one which is in the box with JMeter. try it out and if you need advice on this tool you are welcome to create a new question.

Comment: @alecxe : Alec, please if you see this, can you help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: Well, you can start from http://jmeter.apache.org/ to get overview of the tool and continue from http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#template to create script from scratch. Have you tried to do it?

Comment: I tried to make it from scratch using tutorial "how to log on to web page" and I have success with example.com but I can't manage to log in to routers because it works differently. Router raises small window where you need to write username and password... if you can help me with this I can continue using jmeter.

Comment: You can use http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager for authentication or follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGkrSFKcj10. It is difficult to help you without seeing your script. You can create a new question with JMeter tag and post link here so that I could track it.

Comment: IT is very simple that I create i jmeter:
- one thread grup set to 1
- one HTTP Request (URL is IP address of the router, method: POST, send parameters with request: username and password)
- one result tree that says:

"Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Unexpected end of file from server"

It is pop-up login window(javascript?) and I think there is another way to do this but I can't find it. All works when I use regular POST form on another webpage.

Comment: What if instead of `button.submit()`, you would find the button and `click()` on it? smth like `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]').click()`. Would it wait forever too?

Comment: It is procedural problem. If I do it manually clicking with mouse I must wait. Or not wait and close the window after 2 minutes and open new and update next router. Or after 2 minutes enter new URL in that window. Every "click" make selenium wait much longer than 2 minutes.
I hope you understand me.
I can try click procedure but I think it will be the same. updating routers take 2 minutes just for upload, and another 2 to reconnect (which I want to evade and do not wait to reconnect)

Answer (score 1):

see if this works.

```
try
{
br.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
global ip
br.get("http://"+ip+"/upload.html")
button = br.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file" and  @name="filename"]')
button.send_keys("/home/djura/Downloads/KW5815A_update_140417")
button.submit()
print ("Odradjen UPDATE SOFTWARE-a!")
return

}
catch(TimeoutException e)
{
print("2min over");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably because you are using `button.submit`, which if I'm not mistaken waits for the return of the action. So instead you should find the **actual submit button** and click on it using `click`, e.g.

```
submit_button = br.find_element_by_id('SUBMIT_BTN_ID')
submit_button.click()
```

P.S. the fact that in your example code your `button` variable actually refers to an input element is misleading.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is not misleading, it is actually working but it is a robot. When I manually click "submit" button it is waiting for action to finish. But when I do it manually I can close window and start another to open new link. I am trying to find a solution to to this in selenium without opening and closing window every time.